# Why isn't React component re-rendering each time?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

Here's an overview of my `App.js` file:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    dispatch(getCurrentSession());
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <AppContext>
          <Router />
          <InitAppData />
        </AppContext>
      </ThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

The `Router` is the parent component, inside of which is the bulk of the components, including `Login`.

`InitAppData` has one purpose: to populate an `AppContext`.  It runs fine when I refresh the browser but when I initially login, it fails to run (reload) after a successful login.  Is this because `InitAppData` is not a parent of `Router`, which is the parent of `Login`?

How would you recommend I fix this?

Comment: It sounds like `InitAppData` makes a call and is not a visual element on the page. If this is correct, why not put the logic somewhere else, such as in an action?

Comment: Thanks, Andrew.  I did something similar.